# Shiny actionButton to delete rows in datatable (with code)

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have a Shiny app with an actionButton that when clicked runs a function querying a database and returns the resulting table.  I then display the table in the app as a datatable.

This works fine.

```
sqlOutput <- eventReactive(input$sqlButton, {

  sqlScript(conn, ...)

})

output$sqlSearchResults <- DT::renderDT(server = TRUE, {
  DT::datatable(sqlOutput()[[1]],
                rownames = FALSE,
                extensions = c("FixedColumns"),
                class = 'cell-border stripe',
                ... )
})
```

However I also have another actionButton "deleteRows" that I want to use to delete selected rows when clicked. I have added an observeEvent that assigns the modified table to a new variable. The new variable "testdf" is then used by the datatable output.  But it doesn't work. The error reads *Warning: Error in inherits: object 'testdf' not found* with the line number corresponding to the datatable output.

```
sqlOutput <- eventReactive(input$sqlButton, {

  sqlScript(conn, ...)

})


observeEvent(input$deleteRows,{

  if (!is.null(input$sqlSearchResults_rows_selected)) {
    testdf <- sqlOutput()[[1]][-as.numeric(input$sqlSearchResults_rows_selected),]
  } else testdf <- sqlOutput()[[1]]

})



output$sqlSearchResults <- DT::renderDT(server = TRUE, {
  DT::datatable(testdf,
                rownames = FALSE,
                extensions = c("FixedColumns"),
                class = 'cell-border stripe',
                ... )
})
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please see my updated answer. Also, just a side note - you should probably have edited your question rather than add answers. That seems to be best practice so that other people can follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Difficult to test without a min reprex but `testdf` is not available outside of the `observeEvent({})` and is therefore unavailable to `renderDT({})` so you need to use [reactiveValues](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.4.0/reactiveValues.html). See below and notice the use of `values$testdf` in place of just `testdf`:

```
sqlOutput <- eventReactive(input$sqlButton, {

  sqlScript(conn, ...)

})

values <- reactiveValues()

observeEvent(input$deleteRows,{

  if (!is.null(input$sqlSearchResults_rows_selected)) {
    values$testdf <- sqlOutput()[[1]][-as.numeric(input$sqlSearchResults_rows_selected),]
  } else values$testdf <- sqlOutput()[[1]]

})



output$sqlSearchResults <- DT::renderDT(server = TRUE, {
  DT::datatable(values$testdf,
                rownames = FALSE,
                extensions = c("FixedColumns"),
                class = 'cell-border stripe',
                ... )
})
```

**Update**

Please try below:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(skin = "blue", title = "",
                    dashboardHeader(),
                    dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(id="sidebarmenu",
                                                 sidebarMenuOutput("menusidebar"))),
                    dashboardBody(fluidRow(column(12,
                                                  tabItems(tabItem(tabName ="home", uiOutput("homePage")))))
                    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$menusidebar <- renderMenu({menuItem("Home", tabName = "home", icon = icon("home"))})

    dframe <- data.frame(Category = LETTERS[1:26],
                         Value = 1:26)


    dfOutput <- eventReactive(input$genDF, {
        dfResult <- dframe

    })

    values <- reactiveValues()

    observeEvent(dfOutput(), {
        if(!is.null(dfOutput())){
            values$testdf <- dfOutput()
        }
    })

    observeEvent(input$deleteRows,{
        if (!is.null(input$dfResults_rows_selected)) {
            values$testdf <- values$testdf[-input$dfResults_rows_selected,]
        }
    })





    output$dfResults <- DT::renderDT(server = TRUE, {
        DT::datatable(values$testdf,
                      rownames = FALSE,
                      extensions = c("FixedColumns", "Buttons"),
                      class = 'cell-border stripe',
                      options = list(dom = 'ft',
                                     pageLength = nrow(values$testdf))
        )
    })





    output$homePage <- renderUI({
        fluidPage(
            fluidRow(
                column(3, actionButton("genDF", "Generate Data Frame")),
                column(9,
                       actionButton("deleteRows", strong("Delete Filtered Rows")),
                       DT::dataTableOutput("dfResults"))
            )
        )
    })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This is the key line:

```
values$testdf <- values$testdf[-input$dfResults_rows_selected,]
```

You must use `values$testdf` as the next time you press delete it will then keep track of previous deletions unless you refresh `dfOutput()`. Also key is `input$dfResults_rows_selected`. The datatable name is `dfResults`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Eli. I'm getting there. Using the modified code below the initial table is loaded which is an improvement, but unfortunately when deleteButton is clicked the table returns "No data available in table".

```
sqlOutput <- eventReactive(input$sqlButton, {

  sqlScript(conn, ...)

})

values <- reactiveValues()

observeEvent(icdOutput(), {
    if(!is.null(sqlOutput()[[1]])){
      values$testdf <- sqlOutput()[[1]]
    }
  })

observeEvent(input$deleteRows,{
  if (!is.null(input$sqlSearchResults_rows_selected)) {
    values$testdf <- sqlOutput()[[1]][-as.numeric(input$sqlSearchResults_rows_selected),]
  }
})

output$sqlSearchResults <- DT::renderDT(server = TRUE, {
  DT::datatable(values$testdf,
                rownames = FALSE,
                extensions = c("FixedColumns"),
                class = 'cell-border stripe',
                ... )
})
```

I've also tried

```
... values$testdf <- values$testdf[-as.numeric(input$sqlSearchResults_rows_selected),] ...
```

But it still returns no data when deleteButton is clicked.

Comment: Hi Andrew. Unfortunately I can't get any further without dummy data and a proper min reprex. Maybe you could save the sql table as a data.frame and post a sample set to allow us to test properly. Also, we would need a fully workable shiny app (min reprex) for the best chance at assisting you further. Everything above seems okay from what you have given us.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Eli.  I think your approach is correct. Probably something simple. Here is my app. Its producing the same result.

Sorry I didn't isolate the home tab so you will need to click on it in the sidebar menu.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(skin = "blue", title = "",
                    dashboardHeader(),
                    dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(id="sidebarmenu",
                                                 sidebarMenuOutput("menusidebar"))),
                    dashboardBody(fluidRow(column(12,
                                                  tabItems(tabItem(tabName ="home", uiOutput("homePage")))))
                    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$menusidebar <- renderMenu({menuItem("Home", tabName = "home", icon = icon("home"))})

  dframe <- data.frame(Category = LETTERS[1:26],
                       Value = 1:26)


  dfOutput <- eventReactive(input$genDF, {
    dfResult <- dframe

  })

  values <- reactiveValues()

  observeEvent(dfOutput(), {
    if(!is.null(dfOutput())){
      values$testdf <- dfOutput()
    }
  })

  observeEvent(input$deleteRows,{
    if (!is.null(input$dfResults_rows_selected)) {
      values$testdf <- dfOutput()[-as.numeric(input$sqlSearchResults_rows_selected),]
    }
  })





  output$dfResults <- DT::renderDT(server = TRUE, {
    DT::datatable(values$testdf,
                  rownames = FALSE,
                  extensions = c("FixedColumns", "Buttons"),
                  class = 'cell-border stripe',
                  options = list(dom = 'ft',
                                 pageLength = nrow(values$testdf))
    )
  })





  output$homePage <- renderUI({
    fluidPage(
      fluidRow(
        column(3, actionButton("genDF", "Generate Data Frame")),
        column(9,
               actionButton("deleteRows", strong("Delete Filtered Rows")),
               DT::dataTableOutput("dfResults"))
      )
    )
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```